# Deploy Qt app to android with own plugin structure

Tags: android, qt, plugins, deployment

I wrote a plugin based client-app for Windows, OSX and Linux in Qt.
Now I would like to port it to Android.

The main Application runs fine on Android.
Now my Problem:

The App is looking for Plugins in a Plugin Folder:

```
├── app<br>
├── plugins<br>
│   ├── SomePlugin<br>
│   │   ├── SomePlugin.pluginInfo<br>
│   │   └── libSomePlugin.so<br>
│   ├── OtherPlugin<br>
│   │   ├── OtherPlugin.pluginInfo<br>
│   │   └── libOtherPlugin.so<br>
│   ├── AnotherPlugin<br>
│   │   ├── AnotherPlugin.pluginInfo<br>
│   │   └── libAnotherPlugin.so<br>
```

After deployment debug output shows me the plugin-dir as:

```
D/Qt( 3248): [...]: "plugindir:/data/app/org.qtproject.debugbuild-1/lib/arm"
```

How can a add a subfolder plugins/ to the deployment and add the corresponding libPlugin.so and Plugin.pluginInfo files?

I tried adding them to the bundled_in_lib array in the libs.xml but it does not add the wanted files and folders (no error output while building the .apk they just do not get added).

Oh BTW I am using Android SDK Tools 24.0.2 and
Android NDK r10d.

Comment: I just implemented a workaround:
The installed application is creating the Folders on start-up on the device and moving the required Files to their position.
Would be nice to have the functionality to build the .apk as required though. I will open a ticket at Qt.
If somebody solves this please reply... Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on stock android 5.0.1+ ( And possibly other vendors specific versions such as TouchWiz will have selinux enforcing pre lollipop ) because of selinux, which prohibits loading libraries from a writable directory